# Tap recognizer not getting added

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, xcode4.2

I am using following code

```
@property (retain, nonatmoic) UIImageView *imgView;

  if ( count == 6)
    {
        [timer invalidate]; 
         imgView= [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,460)];

        if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        {
            imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ipad_popover-incorrectguess.png"];
            [self.view addSubview:imgView];

        }
        else if ( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
        {
            imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone_popover-incorrectguess.png"];
            [self.view addSubview:imgView];        
        }
        UIGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                    initWithTarget:self action:@selector(newRound)];
        [imgView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    }
}

-(void)newRound
{
    [imgView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

it seems that newROUND Is never called when I tap anywhere on the image.

How can i fix that?

Comment: Do you know that the code actually reaches the gesture recognizer creation line? Have you logged imgView.gestureRecognizers to see if it was actually added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable user interaction for imgView:

```
imgView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Unlike a UIView, a UIImageView's userInteractionEnabled property is set to NO by default, so you need to explicitly set it to YES to have it receive touches.

Answer (score 0):

Set tap.delegate =self.

UIGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                    initWithTarget:self action:@selector(newRound)];

**tap.delegate=self;**

[imgView addGestureRecognizer:tap];

Comment: This is incorrect. While gesture recognizers do have delegates, the newRound method is the action defined in the target-action set up in the initialization of the recognizer. No delegate is needed for that to be called.

Answer (score 0):

Also I would be sure the class is delegate for  in the .h header file:

```
@interface View : UIView <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
```